# Why/how is this using the same context? And what do I need to do to handle this

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following razor file. The issue is the final `<DxFormLayoutItem>` at lines 75 .. 78. If I delete those, no error.

```
@page "/Admin/ListClaims"
@using LouisHowe.web.PageModels.Admin

<DxFormLayout>
    <DxFormLayoutGroup Caption="Filter (search)" ColSpanMd="10">
        <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="User:" ColSpanMd="4">
            <DxTextBox ShowClearButton="true" @bind-Text="@SearchUserEmail"></DxTextBox>
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
        <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="Claim value:" ColSpanMd="4">
            <DxTextBox ShowClearButton="true" @bind-Text="@SearchClaimValue"></DxTextBox>
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
        <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="Regular expressions:" ColSpanMd="2">
            <DxCheckBox @bind-Checked="@UseRegex"></DxCheckBox>
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
        <DxFormLayoutItem ColSpanMd="2">
            <DxButton Text="Search" Click="@SearchClaims"></DxButton>
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
    </DxFormLayoutGroup>
    
    <DxFormLayoutGroup Caption="Create new claim" ColSpanMd="2">
        <DxFormLayoutItem ColSpanMd="2">
            <DxButton Text="Create" Click="@CreateClaim"></DxButton>
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
    </DxFormLayoutGroup>

    <DxFormLayoutItem ColSpanMd="12">
        <DxGrid Data="@MatchingClaims"
                PagerNavigationMode="PagerNavigationMode.InputBox"
                PageSizeSelectorVisible="true"
                PageSizeSelectorAllRowsItemVisible="true"
                PageSizeSelectorItems="@(new[] { 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 })">
            <Columns>
                <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="Email">
                    <CellDisplayTemplate Context="rowContext">
                        @{
                            ClaimIdentityUser dataObj = (ClaimIdentityUser)rowContext.DataItem;
                            string url = $"Admin/User?userId={dataObj.Id}";
                        }
                        <NavLink href=@url>@rowContext.Value</NavLink>
                    </CellDisplayTemplate>
                </DxGridDataColumn>
                <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="ClaimType"></DxGridDataColumn>
                <DxGridDataColumn FieldName="ClaimValue"></DxGridDataColumn>
                <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Commands" AllowSort="false">
                    <CellDisplayTemplate Context="rowContext">
                        @{
                            ClaimIdentityUser dataObj = (ClaimIdentityUser)rowContext.DataItem;
                        }
                        <DxButton RenderStyle="ButtonRenderStyle.Primary"
                                  RenderStyleMode="ButtonRenderStyleMode.Text"
                                  Click="@((e) => DeleteClaim(e, dataObj))"
                                  Text="Delete" />
                    </CellDisplayTemplate>
                </DxGridDataColumn>
            </Columns>
        </DxGrid>
    </DxFormLayoutItem>
</DxFormLayout>

<DxWindow @ref=_createClaimWindow
          AllowResize="true"
          ShowCloseButton="true"
          CloseOnEscape="true"
          HeaderText="Create new claim"
          ShowHeader="true"
          ShowFooter="true"
          @bind-Visible=_createClaimWindowVisible>
    <BodyTextTemplate>
        <DxFormLayout>
            <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="User:" ColSpanMd="4">
                <DxTextBox @bind-Text="@Name" />
            </DxFormLayoutItem>
        </DxFormLayout>
    </BodyTextTemplate>
    <FooterTextTemplate>
        <DxButton CssClass="popup-button my-1 ms-2" 
                  RenderStyle="ButtonRenderStyle.Primary" 
                  Text="OK" 
                  Click="AddClaims" />
        <DxButton CssClass="popup-button my-1 ms-2" 
                  RenderStyle="ButtonRenderStyle.Secondary" 
                  Text="Cancel" 
                  Click="@context.CloseCallback" />
    </FooterTextTemplate>
</DxWindow>

@code
{
    string Name { get; set; } = "";
}
```

The errors I get (these both go away if the final `<DxFormLayoutItem Caption="User:" ColSpanMd="4">` is removed:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0115  'ListClaims.OnInitializedAsync()': no suitable method found to override LouisHowe.web   C:\git\LouisHowe\LouisHowe.web\Pages\Admin\ListClaims.razor.cs  87  Active
Error   RZ9999  The child content element 'ChildContent' of component 'DxFormLayoutItem' uses the same parameter name ('context') as enclosing child content element 'BodyTextTemplate' of component 'DxWindow'. Specify the parameter name like: '<ChildContent Context="another_name"> to resolve the ambiguity   LouisHowe.web   C:\git\LouisHowe\LouisHowe.web\CSC  1
```

What is causing this, why is it a problem, and what is the way to address it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another search [I found the answer](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/403276/troubleshooting/common-component-issues/the-child-content-element-uses-the-same-parameter-name):

> When you nest DevExpress Blazor components that contain
> RenderFragment﻿ properties, a Razor error can occur. For
> example, the following code nests a DxButton component within a
> DxFormLayoutItem component.
>
> Both components include properties that specify render fragments:
> DxFormLayoutItem‘s Template and DxButton‘s ChildContent﻿. This means
> that Blazor adds Context﻿ implicit parameters to each component:
>
> The Context parameters have the same default value. This causes the
> following error:
>
> Error RZ9999 The child content element ‘ChildContent’ of component
> ‘DxButton’ uses the same parameter name (‘context’) as enclosing child
> content element ‘Template’ of component ‘DxFormLayoutItem’. Specify
> the parameter name like: ‘’ to
> resolve the ambiguity.
>
> To fix the issue, specify the Context parameter explicitly in one of
> the components: